# C# Write to a RichTextBox in a Form from different classes

Tags: c#

I am using a `RichTextBox` which is in a `Form` that I am basically using as a log window whilst the program performs various functions - much like a debug window. Various methods write to the window as they perform tasks on various files. The simple class looks like this:

```
public partial class ValidationWindow : Form
    {
        public ValidationWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void writeToWindow(string text)
        {
            if (richTextBoxValidationWindow.TextLength > 0)
            {
                richTextBoxValidationWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + text);
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBoxValidationWindow.Text = text;
            }

        }
}
```

I have instantiated the Form containing the textbox from a class in the usual fashion i.e `ValidationWindow valWindow = new ValidationWindow()`, then call the `show()` method to display the window, and i can then write to it using the method in the above class called writeToWindow. All good.

I now need to be able to continue to write to the same window from other classes. I obviously don't want to create more instances of the same Validation Window. So what is the best way to do this please?

Comment: `valWindow.writeToWindow("test")`

Comment: I think you misread. I can write to it no problem from the class i instantiate it from, i'm asking how to write to the SAME window from other classes.

Comment: If you can't use the original reference, you can get one from [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) and call the `writeToWindow()` method on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need access to this form from other forms and classes. In other words, you need this form to be globally accessible.

The simplest way to do this is add a global variable to your application, and save a reference to the logging window in that variable. Then, if any other class needs to log, it can access the logging window via the global variable.

However, this is perhaps not the best way to do this, as you are tying your logging to that window. What happens if you decide to log a different way? You'd have to change every reference to the window, which means changes all over the application. You would be better off looking at something like messages, which allow the calling code to send out a message requesting that something be logged, but not needing to know anything about the class that receives the message and does the actual logging. I know WOF supports this with MVVM, but am not sure how you would do it in WinForms (assuming that's what you're using). Maybe do a search on "winforms messages" and see what comes up.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your constructive comment. I'll certainly look into that now.